# TypeScript-Angular problem when using instance of an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular service that sends requests to a REST API that returns information correctly, and I collect the information coming from the REST API in an object of type User. However, when I try to call a method of this class as soon as I get the instance, it gives an error because it can't find the method. In fact, if I try to execute an operation of type `this._currentUser instanceof User` it returns `false`. How can I fix this?

This is the code of the Angular service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from "../../../model/user.model";
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrentUserService {

    private _currentUser: User | undefined;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this._currentUser = undefined;
    }

    public async getCurrentUser(): Promise<User | undefined> {
        if (this._currentUser === undefined) {
            try {
                this._currentUser = await this.reloadCurrentUserInfo();
                // Calling this._currentUser.isTeacher() here returns error
            } catch (e) {
                return undefined;
            }
        }
        return this._currentUser;
    }

    public disposeCurrentUserInfo = (): void => {
        this._currentUser = undefined;
    }

    private reloadCurrentUserInfo = (): Promise<User> => {
        return lastValueFrom(this.http.get<User>("/currentuser"));
    }
}
```

And here is the model class:

```js
export class User {
    private readonly _id: number;
    private readonly _username: string;
    private readonly _name: string;
    private readonly _lastName: string;

    private readonly _roles: { roleName: string }[];

    private readonly _courses: any[];

    constructor(id: number, username: string, name: string, lastName: string) {
        this._id = id;
        this._username = username;
        this._name = name;
        this._lastName = lastName;

        this._roles = [];
        this._courses = [];
    }


    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }

    get username(): string {
        return this._username;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    get lastName(): string {
        return this._lastName;
    }

    get roles(): string[] {
        return this._roles.map(role => role.roleName);
    }

    public isTeacher(): boolean {
        return this.roles.includes("ROLE_TEACHER");
    }

    get courses(): any[] {
        return this._courses;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The http.get call doesn't return an instance of a User object. It just returns JSON which type aligns to the User class. You've to call the constructor of the class to create an instance of a user. Then, you call a method on the instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Which way would you suggest me to do this in a fast way? Maybe Object.setPrototypeOf()?

Comment: check https://stackblitz.com/edit/ufnlfd?file=CurrentUserService.ts